# How to install java inside a chroot?

Tags: java, chroot

I want to execute a java program inside my debootstrap-chroot on an ubuntu machine for which I need to have java installed inside the chroot jail. I tried to install it using :

```
 apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

but it gives an error:

```
"perl: warning: Setting locale failed"
```

How can I fix this ? or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2):

I got this solved , you just need to mount the /proc filesystem inside the chroot :

```
sudo mount -o bind /proc /chroot/proc
```

then inside chroot , install java

```
#install java
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```